# Issue in configuring pins in MPLAB code configurator

Tags: pic, mcc

I am using PIC16F1829 (SSOP-20 package) and trying to configure pin RC1 as C12IN1-(comparator C1 ) using MPLAB code configurator.

Now the problem is ,I am able to configure 3 pins RA1, RC2, RC3 as  C12IN0-,C12IN2-,C12IN3- respectively but not RC1 as C12IN1-. As pin manager enable only above three pin for comparator 1 input pins.

So anybody can help how to configure  RC1 as C12IN1- as comparator 1 inverting input?
I have checked APFCON0 or APFCON1 settings but i am not able to see option for these settings.

Appreciate the kind help in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have found a bug in the MPLAB Code Configurator.

According to data sheet DS41440B the configuration you need is supported by the PIC16F1829 but I could not get the MCC tool to allocate pin RC1 for the `C12IN-` selection on either comparator. Although all four `C12IN-` slections are available for the PIC16F1825 device.

You will need to take this matter up with the Microchip support by opening a support case, sometimes called a support ticket.

Microchip releases updates to MPLABX about every 3 months. There is no guarantee that Microchip will fix your bug even if you can convince the support staff it is a bug. My experience with them suggests it takes about a month before they take your report seriously.

If you want your PIC16F1829 project working before June you may need to abandon MCC and use the Microchip Libraries for Application (MLA) for sample code.